# .css broken after adding htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a mediawiki installation on the root /public_html directory which I have been using with a htaccess rule (as suggested [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache)) to 
rewrite to /wiki/ using

```
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
```

However I also have a wordpress instalation on /site/ directory which I wanted to add another rewriterule to redirect it to the main domain (where mediawiki is installed), I tried adding

```
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).*)$ site [L]
```

And while the main domain now redirects to domain.com/site, it doesn't rewrite the url completely as I would want and it also broke the mediawiki css which now is not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Browser console displays the following

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://domain.com/site/?debug=false&lang=en&modules=site&only=styles&skin=vector".
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://domain.com/site/?debug=false&lang=en&modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPri…mediawiki.skinning.interface%7Cskins.vector.styles&only=styles&skin=vector".
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://domain.com/site/?debug=false&lang=en&modules=ext.smw.style%7Cext.smw.tooltip.styles&only=styles&skin=vector".
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

So it seems to be grabbing the media wiki css from the wordpress directory which I wanted to redirect to the main domain instead.